# Eclipse-Ivy-Selenium configuration when Ivy.xml and selenium jar kept on server

Tags: java, selenium, ivy

We were trying to automate the test scripts using Selenium-Eclipse-Ivy.
The selenium jar files has to be called through ivy.xml and ivysettings.xml kept on server.
We are not allowed to download the Jar files nor the XML files.
We are not able to understand how we can use those XML files to call the jar.
Also, we are not allowed to modify these files.
Please help us as we are not able to take single step with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the [settings](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/settings.html) task, the ivy [resolve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/resolve.html) task does not support a "url" argument. This means the "ivy.xml" will have to exist locally, whereas the "ivysettings.xml" could quite happily live on the server.

If you really can't support a local ivy.xml file, the only option I can think of is a [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) task, listing the dependencies from within your build file.

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path">
    <dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium" rev="2.0rc2"/>
</ivy:cachepath>
```

Finally, I don't really understand what you mean by not being allowed to download jar files.

Comment: Thanks Mark, The jar files and the xml are not allowed to download on the local machine they has to be used from server only.

Comment: @arbansal I'm confused.....So how does your Java source code (presumably locally) compile against classes contained in jars on the server? ... I suspect your definition of "local" is in debate. Are you running the build on the server? In that case the files would be "local" any downloads performed by ivy would be on the server.